# Applications of symplectic geometry in industry

Tags: soft-question, applications, symplectic-geometry

I am wondering if symplectic geometry is being used anywhere outside of academia? Are there any current applications of symplectic geometry in industry?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207820/are-symplectic-methods-used-in-classical-economics . Symplectic geometry arose in classical mechanics and optics, both of which are used outside academia.

Answer (score 3):

[Symplectic integrators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator) are frequently used in numerical simulation of physical systems, since they preserve symmetries of the original system, and tend to have good energy conservation also. I can't say for sure that they are used in industry, but I know at least one person who did her Ph.D. on symplectic integrators in computer graphics, and then went to work for a big special effects firm (and turned down a job at Pixar).